# How to update Ubuntu from Windows in a dual boot setup without booting into it

Tags: 11.04, updates

Is it possible to update Ubuntu in a dual boot setup with Windows 7, without booting into Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean by updating ubuntu? A distro upgrade? A normal package update?

Comment: He is talking about upgrading to 11.04, check the tag

Comment: @Ashfame That doesn't seem clear from the tagging. `11.04` could just as well be the release currently being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily, ubuntu is probably installed on an ext3 (or 4) partition and windows can't read that file system without installing some exotic extras, which I've heard don't work very well.

You might be able to do something if you installed Ubuntu via wubi but I don't think it currently has the ability to update yet, only install and uninstall.

The best solution might be to boot into Ubuntu and update it that way, or not update it. If you have no intention of ever booting into ubuntu, then why would you need to update it?